# Redirect to a page using a button

Tags: javascript, html

this is my code

JS :

```
function addterm(){
    var f=document.form;
    f.method="post";
    f.action='admin_addterm.jsp';
    f.submit();
}
```

HTML :

```
<label>Add Terms:</label><input type="text" name="term" id="term" >
<input type="button" name="term_b" id="term_b" value ="Add" onclick="addterm();"/>
```

When I press the button it is supposed to go to another page which populates the database.
The above action doesnt redirect to the other page.Is something wrong with the code.I had used the same code previously but with a parameter(id) passed within the function addterm().

Answer (score 0):

it's document.forms[N]
where N is the number of form you are trying to access

Answer (score 0):

Try this way :

```
function addterm(){
    var f=document.forms[0];
    // or var f=document.forms['your_form_name'];
    f.method="post";
    f.action='admin_addterm.jsp';
    f.submit();
}
```

Comment: the first form which was present in your document

Comment: I have another form also...which is above this one

Comment: give your form a name and then use its name to access it

Comment: check now if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Please test with few online url , i thinks  i have find issue in url path .

f.action='http://google.com/';

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i also tested it

```
<script language="javascript">
                            function addterm() {
                                var f = document.forms[0];
                                f.method = "post";
                                f.action = 'admin_addterm.jsp';
                                f.submit();
                            }
</script>
```

Comment: Yours went to the next page.but gave a null value.Also i have another form before this(proper form which has submit button)

Comment: If you have multiple forms and want to access a specific form 
then you can assign 'name' attribute of that form and use 
document.forms['form_name']